# "a inside div" adds a bottom padding of 3 pixels

Tags: css, layout, html

I have a  containing an `<a>` containing an `<img>`.

All elements are styles with border,padding,margin set to 0.

The size of the image is the size of the div, as shown in firebug.

Firebug shows the a link does not extend to the whole size of the img or div. Instead it occupies some space at the bottom, and extended 3 pixels below the div.
How do I get rid of them? The a tag has `text-decoration: none;`

Thanks.

Comment: Please give an example at jsfiddle

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/johngoche99/M6w9H/2/

Comment: Then launch firefox and with firebug select the "a" element. You will see it extends below the image by 3 pixels.

Comment: Furthermore the a element does not seem to extend to the whole height of the image in firebug, even though the whole image is clickable.

Comment: `a` isn't a block element so put `a{display:block}` to take the `img` height -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6w9H/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mention `display:block` in the image style

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```

[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/M6w9H/4/)

Comment: That does the trick. Why is it necessary to set the img's display to block though. How does the trick work? I would like to understand the fix.

Comment: check this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images%2c_Tables%2c_and_Mysterious_Gaps it had a very good description of the problem